# Using request.getAsync from bluebird, how to 'pipe' to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to get the content of some pdf's file asynchronously. To do that I'm using `Promise.mapSeries` with `request.getAsync` and `spread` from **bluebird**.

But in the `then` I need to get the result of that `request` using `pipe` and `createWriteStream` directly. Something like:

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
```

This is the code, I'm using:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'), { multiArgs: true });
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

const urls = ['http://localhost/test-pdf/one.pdf', 'http://localhost/test-pdf/two.pdf'];

Promise.mapSeries(urls, url => {
    return request.getAsync({url: url, encoding:'binary'}).spread((response, body) => {
        if (response.statusCode == 200){
            let r = {};
            r.name = url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1]; // get the last part of url (file name)
            r.content = body;
            console.log(`Getting ${r.name}`);
            return r;
        }
        else if (response.statusCode == 404){
            console.log(`The archive ${url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1]} does not exists`);
        }
        else throw new Error(`Unsuccessful attempt. Code: ${response.statusCode}`);
    });
}).then((result) => {
    // Here I want to 'pipe' to a file the result from 'getAsync'
}).catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
})
```

My question:

How can I *pipe* to a file the result from `getAsync` using the `pipe` function ? It is possible?

**PD:** I know that I can use `fs.promises`, but just want to know if it's possible to do it in the way I'm posting

Comment: As a comment -and after the answer and comments below- I just want to quote what says [here](https://github.com/request/request-promise#api-in-detail): "_**STREAMING THE RESPONSE** (e.g. `.pipe(...)`) is **DISCOURAGED** because Request-Promise would grow the memory footprint for large requests unnecessarily high. Use the original Request library for that. You can use both libraries in the same project_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is already in the question in that `.then()` seems to be the `.pipe()` you seek.

What's possibly missing is that `(result)` should be `(results)`, ie. an array of all the `{name, content}` pairs arising from `Promise.mapSeries(urls, ...)`.

```
Promise.mapSeries(urls, url => {
    return request.getAsync({'url':url, 'encoding':'binary'}).spread((response, body) => {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            return {
                'name': url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1], // get the last part of url (file name)
                'content': body
            };
        } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
            throw new Error(`The archive ${url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1]} does not exist`);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unsuccessful attempt. Code: ${response.statusCode}`);
        }
    });
}).then((results) => {
    // Here write each `result.content` to file.
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

In practice you would probably not choose to write it that way because every `getAsync()` would need to complete before any of the writes commenced.

A better flow under most circumstances (and probably the one you want) would be for content from each successful `getAsync()` to be written as soon as possible :

```
Promise.mapSeries(urls, url => {
    let name = url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1]; // get the last part of url (file name)
    return request.getAsync({'url':url, 'encoding':'binary'}).spread((response, body) => {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            // write `body.content` to file.
        } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
            throw new Error(`The archive ${name} does not exist`);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unsuccessful attempt. Code: ${response.statusCode}`);
        }
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Going further, you might choose to handle errors better, for example you may wish to :

- catch individual url/get/write errors
- compile success/failure stats.

Something like this maybe :

```
Promise.mapSeries(urls, url => {
    let name = url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1] || ''; // get the last part of url (file name)
    if(!name) {
        throw new RangeError(`Error in input data for ${url}`);
    }
    return request.getAsync({'url':url, 'encoding':'binary'}).spread((response, body) => {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            // write `body.content` to file.
            return { name, 'content': body };
        } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
            throw new Error(`The archive ${name} does not exist`);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unsuccessful attempt. Code: ${response.statusCode}`);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => ({ name, error }));
}).then((results) => {
    let successes = results.filter(res => !res.error).length;
    let failures = results.filter(res => !!res.error).length;
    let total = results.length;
    console.log({ successes, failures, total }); // log success/failure stats
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error); // just in case some otherwise uncaught error slips through
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, interesting one! I upvoted it and I'm going to try your ideas. I'll be back later.

Comment: Just point that the _first_ `.catch`, should be `.catch( error => ({ name, error }) );` There are two ways to return objects from arrow functions: either adding a return to the block body `x => { return {}}` or to mark it as an expression `x => ({})` - both are valid and work.

Comment: Ok, I have tried your code, and I like it, but .... my question is: Where you can put the function `pipe` in `request.getAsync(url).spread( (response,body) => { } )` ??? It is possible ???

Comment: Which `pipe` function are you hoping to use? Where have you read about it? And what do you expect of it that is not already achieved?

Comment: When I use _normal_ request I can output directly the result to a file using `pipe`: `request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_name));` That's what I mean. I want to know exactly if the same thing can be done with `request.getAsync(url).spread ...`

Comment: No, `.pipe()` is a  method of the object returned by `request()`. By using `request.getAsync()` you have chosen to start a promise chain which will comprise promise methods such as `.then()` and `.catch()` (and Bluebird's `.spread()`). The advantage of promises is that they simplify/standardize the inter-operation of asynchronous activities. It's possible that you don't need to full power of promises in what you are doing here.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks for your help and time my friend.